# Append Form with jQuery in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to append a form to a div tag

```
$('#courses_ajax').html('<h1>Materie: <%= @course.name %></h1>');
msg = "<form accept-charset='UTF-8' action='/add_by_course' class='form-horizontal' data-remote='true' id='add_by_courses_id' method='post'>";
msg += "<table class='table table-condensed table-bordered'>";
msg +="<th>Nume Elev</th><th>Nota</th><th>Absente</th>";
<% @students.each do |student|%>
  msg +="<tr><td><%= student.name%></td>";
  msg +="<td><input class='span2' id='course_grade' name='grade[student_id]' size='30' type='number' min=1 max=10 /></td>";
  msg +="<td><input class='span2' id='course_absence' name='absence[student_id]' size='30' type='datetime' /></td>";
  msg +="</tr>";
<%end%>  
msg +="</table><input class='btn-primary' name='commit' type='submit' value='Salveaza' />";
msg +="</form>";
$('#courses_ajax').append(msg);
```

All the helper methods don't seem to work in js.erb files , is there a better more cleaner way to do this , maybe I'm missing something .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that it is better to use partials here. Create a partial and put html and helpers there. Then put into you js.erb file:

```
$('#courses_ajax').append("<%= escape_javascript(
render :partial => "your_partial", :object => your_varable, 
:locals => {:your_other_var => value, ...}  %>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Rendering a partial with the contents in pure html solves it
BUT I recommend you let rails render it like:

```
<%= form_for(@xxxx) ... %> ... "html here" ... <%end%>
```

as that will protect you from CSRF attacks generating an "authenticity_token".

It did not work for me to add more rails generated `<%= %>` input fields, but with the `<%= form ... %>` is good enough.